# Reusing/Shared framework inside Xcode Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

[image]

Hello, in my project here's the structure

**Main project**

- **FrameworkProject**

  - *FrameworkA.xcframework*
  - *FrameworkB.xcframework*
- FrameworkA.xcframework
- FrameworkB.xcframework

> **FrameworkProject** - has dependencies on FrameworkA and FrameworkB

> **My main project** should be able to access FrameworkA and FrameworkB directly as well.

### Issue:

#### My main problem is that FrameworkProject fails to load the embedded frameworks inside it. :/

#### Any good suggestions for this structure? I'm trying to find a way where I can just use one .xcframework once and not reimporting.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the output(error) ?

Are you sure the xcframework is ok ?

Your Frameworks `FrameworkA.xcframework` and `FrameworkB.xcframework` do not look like xcframeworks. How did you import them ?

An imported xcframework has this icon: [image]

Go to your App (Click on the project, select the right target, `general` tab, `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` and add it there.